# Expectation of exponential of integral of absolute value of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, expectation, brownian-motion

Sorry about all the "of"s in the title... here's my problem:

I want to compute the expected value of 
$$
\exp\bigg\{ C \int_0^t |W_s|ds\bigg\}
$$
where $W$ is a Brownian motion and $C$ is a positive constant.

My trouble comes from the absolute value (if the absolute value weren't there it would be the exponential of a Gaussian process). What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution for the 
$$Y = \int_0^1 |W_s|ds$$
 is worked on in [On the Distribution of the Integral of the Absolute Value of the Brownian Motion](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1177005514) Takacs (1993).  It isn't very pretty:
$$P(Y \leq x) = H(x)$$
where
$$\frac{dH(x)}{dx} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{x \sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{j=1}^\infty C_j e^{-v_j}v_j^{2/3} U(1/6, 4/3, v_j)$$
where 
     $$C_j = \frac{1 + 3\int_0^{a_j'} Ai(-u) du}{3 a_j'Ai(-a_j')}$$
where $a_j'$ are the zeros of the Airy integral (Ai), and $U$ is a confluent hypergeometric function, and
$$v_j = \frac{2(a_j')^3}{27x^2}$$
So from all there, you can compute
$$E[e^{\int_0^1 |W_s| ds}] = \int_0^\infty e^{Cx}\frac{dH(x)}{dx}dx$$

The paper also does work out expression for the $k$th moment $E[Y^k]$ of $H(x)$.  Perhaps you can combine those to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E[Y^k]}{k!}$.

Comment: I actually just came across that paper. Yes, it's not pretty, but this is what I will try. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Also, your $Y_t$ should just be a $Y$ (there's no $t$ dependence)

Comment: I mean, I have $t$ dependence, but can scale the $[0,t]$ integral to $[0,1]$ and have something like your $Y$.